# discord.py - Getting Guild ID on 'on_guild_join' event

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a simple Discord Bot with Python. I just want to save guild id on a SQLite folder, I can't get guild id. I'm new on that database things. Parameters on event doesn't work like:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(ctx):
   dbase = sqlite3.connect('dbase.sqlite')
   cursor = dbase.cursor()
   cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(guild_id TEXT)')
   cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO data (guild_id) VALUES ({ctx.guild.id})')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[on_guild_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.on_guild_join) only has the parameter of [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.Guild) and not Context.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
   dbase = sqlite3.connect('dbase.sqlite')
   cursor = dbase.cursor()
   cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(guild_id TEXT)')
   cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO data (guild_id) VALUES ({guild.id})')
```